# Oracle User permission error trying to create table in another schema after seemingly being granted rights

Tags: oracle

ADMIN Ran:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO APP_DBA_ROLE WITH ADMIN OPTION;
Grant succeeded
GRANT CREATE ANY INDEX TO APP_DBA_ROLE WITH ADMIN OPTION;
Grant succeeded

GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO APP_DBA_ROLE WITH ADMIN OPTION;
Grant succeeded
GRANT ALTER ANY INDEX TO APP_DBA_ROLE WITH ADMIN OPTION;

GRANT APP_DBA_ROLE TO JOE;
Grant succeeded
```

JOE Ran:

```
CREATE TABLE FDS_MAINT.LOG (LOG_ID NUMBER)
successfully created

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FDS_MAINT.LOG ON FDS_MAINT.LOG (LOG_ID);
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I was expecting that the index would be successfully created since the admin seemingly granted me rights to be able to do so, especially since I was able to create the table. Why not the index also?

Comment: Did JOE log out and back in after the role grant? I tested your sequence of commands and it worked properly.

Comment: I logged out and back in just now and it worked but I swear I tried that before. I tried it now and it works. I might have done something else in the interim that could have contributed to it. For example, I was looking into this: 

GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO APP_DBA_ROLE WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT APP_DBA_ROLE TO Joe;

Joe could NOT select from a table in another users schema

GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO JOE WITH ADMIN OPTION;
Joe COULD  select from a table in another users schema